# Github doesn't show the right author of a commit

Tags: git, github

I have an account on github and I am the owner of an organization.

I don't understand why when I do 'git commit' an then 'git push' the webpage shows the name of the organization as author of the commit.

When I run 'git push' I use the username and the password of my account.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The commit user will not be affected by `git push`, you need to commit as the correct user.

You can set this by doing:

```
git config --global user.name "My Name"
git config --global user.email me@example.com
```

If you want to fix the last existing commit (that has NOT been pushed), you can do

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

Comment: @lucaghera if you really need to change the repo's history: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info

Comment: @Wivlaro Thanks, it worked. However I wasn't able to fix the name by using the option `--local`. What If have hundred of repo with the global user an one, this one, with another user name? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go to your project folder.

Under ".git/config" you can see your information.

```
[user]
    name = xxx
    email = xxx
```

Perhaps your informations are wrong.

Comment: thank, it worked. But why when I do git push it alway ask for username and password? Thanks!

Comment: @maverick did you use git ssh url or the https?